# Как с Recovery определить версию Android?

Tags: android, recovery

Моя задача: проверить версию установленного Android из Recovery. Делаю это так:

```
android_version == file_getprop("/system/system/build.prop", "ro.build.version.sdk");
```

Но в Recovery я получаю значение именно самого Recovery (а не установленной системы, устройство system-as-root). А как проверить-то версию Android? Т е, `ro.build.version.sdk` у меня 29, но получаю 25, как будто из Recovery.

Comment: А чем Build.VERSION.SDK_INT не устраивает?

Comment: Лучше фрагмент кода скинь тогда, а то я реально не понял, о чем ты. Я так-то не особо горю желанием писать на Edify, но это ж Recovery... Magisk же все по человечески, через install.sh делает (и то есть тот же ui_print)...

Comment: а shell-скрипт запустить не могу, оно почему-то не может в execv...

Comment: а, сорри. Я думал java )